# Connect directly with Tor Browser (as in, bypass Tor)?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, vpn, proxy

I recently decided to pay for CryptoStorm anonymous VPN as an extra layer to my privacy protection - so that all requests including UDP requests are automatically masked. As I understand it, all traffic through the VPN is routed through the Tor network as well.

So I don't think it's necessary for me to be additionally running Tor locally (correct me if I'm misunderstanding something here).

However, I would still like to use the Tor browser, as it takes care of many other security concerns - like protection from WebRTC detection and other JavaScript-based vulnerabilities.

Is there any way to run the Tor browser without proxying through Tor? I tried setting "No proxy" in the network settings, but it just says "Unable to find the proxy server" - suggesting the browser is hard-wired to run through the Tor proxy.

Or if it isn't possible to connect directly with TBB, is there another browser (probably another fork of Firefox) which would cover all the same client-side security concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to disable Torbutton.

At the top of the connection settings dialog, it indicates this: "Disable Torbutton to change these settings."

In `about:addons` you can disable *Torbutton* and *TorLauncher* and then quit/relaunch the browser. Then you can set your own proxy settings or none in the network connection settings.

**Edit to add:** If you don't use a proxy, you must also disable `Remote DNS` in network connection settings. Even thought it is greyed out when `No Proxy` is selected, it must be unchecked.

**Edit: Better and more complete instructions:**

1. Type in `about:addons` in the URL bar.
2. In that page, disable **Torbutton** and **TorLauncher** add-ons.
3. Restart the browser as prompted.
4. Click on **Menu** (3 horizontal bars logo located at top-left) > **Preferences**/**Options** >
   **Advance vertical tab** > **Network horizontal tab**.
5. Click on the **Settings** button on the right of "Connection"
   label (while you are in that tab) which opens up the proxy configuration window.
6. Untick **Remote DNS** checkbox (At center-right of the window).
7. Change your proxy settings accordingly to your own proxy or to no proxy
   and click OK.
8. Congratulations have de-torified the Tor browser!

Comment: I missed that! Unfortunately, I just tried this and it still doesn't work. I disabled Torbutton and TorLauncher, restarted the browser, then set "no proxy", but I still get "Unable to find the proxy server". I also tried "Auto-detect..." and "Use system...", but to no avail. Am I missing a step?

Comment: I've tested back and forth a bit and it's weird. I now think that `Remote DNS` must also be disabled. Even tho it is greyed out when `No Proxy` is selected, it must be unchecked. So it seems...

Comment: @Joblwan BOOM! It works! Thanks you :) Could you add the extre remote DNS step to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Menu (3 horizontal bars logo located at top-left)  is on the right side.

There is no preferences/Options under menu...just options.

There is no "Connection Label"

Instead I went to Network Proxy label at bottom.... Clicked settings on the right side.

The only option that worked was "Use system proxy settings" all other settings stated they could not find proxy server.